# xamarin forms win phone 8.1 background tasks for push notifications not registering

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms, background-task, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I am attempting to register a background task for a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app but have not been able to successfully achieve this. From the samples I have seen online I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Anyhow below are some snapshots of the settings I configured and code snippets. If anyone could please enlighten me with what I'm missing I'd greatly appreciate it!

**Win Phone project (WMAppManifest.xml)**

[image: Notification Service]

[image: Push Notification enabled]

**Win Phone project (Package.appxmanifest)**

[image: Toastable and Lockscreen enabled]

[image: Background task configuration]

**Background task project type**

[image: Background project type]

**WinPhone Notification Manager**

*This class inherits an interface which is used to call the register events for the notification hub using a dependency from the PCL*

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Notification;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApp.Common.Models;
using MyApp.Interfaces;
using MyApp.Utilities;
using MyApp.WinPhone;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PushNotificationManager))]
namespace MyApp.WinPhone
{
    public class PushNotificationManager : IPushNotificationManager
    {
        private NotificationHub hub;

        private const string TASK_NAME = "NotificationTask";
        private const string TASK_ENTRY_POINT = "MyApp.Background.NotificationTask";

        public PushNotificationManager() { }

        public async Task RegisterDevice()
        {
            try
            {
                var channel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("NotificationChannel");
                if (channel == null)
                {
                    channel = new HttpNotificationChannel("NotificationChannel");
                    channel.Open();
                    channel.BindToShellToast();
                }

                // Register device
                channel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(NotificationChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                channel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(NotificationChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
                channel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(NotificationChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);

                // Clean out the background task
                await UnregisterBackgroundTask();
                await RegisterBackgroundTask();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public async Task UnregisterDevice()
        {
            var channel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("NotificationChannel");

            if (channel != null)
            {
                var hub = new NotificationHub(Utilities.Constants.ApplicationHubName, Utilities.Constants.ApplicationConnectionString);
                await hub.UnregisterAllAsync(channel.ChannelUri.ToString());
                channel.Close();

                // Clean out the background task
                await UnregisterBackgroundTask();
            }
        }

        protected void NotificationChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterWinDevice(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
        }

        protected void NotificationChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get title and message

                CreateNotification(title, message);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        protected void NotificationChannel_HttpNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get title and message

                CreateNotification(title, message);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private async Task RegisterWinDevice(string channelUri)
        {
            try
            {
                hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.ApplicationHubName, Constants.ApplicationConnectionString);

                var tags = new List<string>() { };
                User user = LocalStorage.GetUserInfo();
                tags.Add(user.Id.ToString());

                var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channelUri, tags.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void CreateNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            //Show toast notification
        }

        private async Task RegisterBackgroundTask()
        {
            BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            PushNotificationTrigger trigger = new PushNotificationTrigger();

            await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

            // Background tasks must live in separate DLL, and be included in the package manifest
            // Also, make sure that your main application project includes a reference to this DLL
            taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = TASK_ENTRY_POINT;
            taskBuilder.Name = TASK_NAME;
            taskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);

            try
            {
                BackgroundTaskRegistration task = taskBuilder.Register();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await UnregisterBackgroundTask();
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> UnregisterBackgroundTask()
        {
            foreach (var iter in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                IBackgroundTaskRegistration task = iter.Value;
                if (task.Name == TASK_NAME)
                {
                    task.Unregister(true);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Background task project (NotificationTask)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.Networking.PushNotifications;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

namespace MyApp.Background
{
    public sealed class NotificationTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            //Get Raw Notification and show Toast Notification
        }
    }
}
```

Some more things to note: The phone registers properly to Azures notification hub and there are no errors thrown when running the application or when I send a push notification. In the *Lifecycle Events toolbar* I don't see the background task after it registers. Some more screen captures with these points...

**Registered Phone**

[image: Registered windows phone]

**Lifecycle Events toolbar**

[image: Lifecycle event no background task]

And finally one thing I noticed is that the trigger I set on the background task when I register it returns null... (maybe my error is here?) Below is a picture of this:

[image: Null Trigger]

**UPDATE**

Updated the life cycle event screen capture showing there is no background task. Also I noticed if i add "System Event" to the Package.appxmanifest and change my trigger to a system event when registering the Background task starts working...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue..... But I upgraded from 8.0 to 8.1 Silverlight....
Then I followed this to the T, and it fixed my problems:
[Upgrade from 8 to 8.1 SL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx)

The major issue was the WMAppManifest.xml should NOT have push notifications checked. But the Package.appxmanifest MUST have it checked...